# Show that no periodic function is one to one.

Tags: real-analysis

I would just like to get some feedback if the following proof outline I have written is correct.

*Claim.* If $f$ is periodic, then $f$ is not injective.

*Proof.* Assume to the contrary that $f$ is periodic and $f$ is injective. Then by definition, $\exists$p $\in \mathbb{R}$\ {$0$}, such that $f(x+p) = f(x)$ for all $x\in$ dom $f$. Let $x_1,x_2 \in$ dom $f$. Since $f$ is injective, $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ and so by definition it follows that $x_1 = x_2$. Now,

$f(x_1) = f(x_2)$

$\Longrightarrow f(x_1) = f(x_2+p)$; because $f$ is periodic

$\Longrightarrow x_1 = x_2 + p$

$\Longrightarrow x_1 - x_2 = p$

$\Longrightarrow 0 = p$; by assumption that $f$ is injective

but by assumption $p \neq 0$ which is a contradiction.

Hence, no periodic function is injective. $\Box$

Comment: Are $x_1$ and $x_2$ are two arbitrary points in $\text{dom} f$? If so, why does $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$? In any case, I think you are making this more complicated than necessary. If $f$ is periodic then there is a nonzero $p$ with $f(x) = f(x+p)$ for all $x$. So, if we fix an arbitrary $x$ then $f(x) = f(x+p)$ but $x \neq x+p$. Therefore $f$ is not injective.

Comment: I don't understand the statement "Since $f$ is injective, $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$"  .  Your $x_i$ were defined without restrictions, so I don't think your claim is true.  But, more simply, pick any $x$ in the domain of $f$ and remark that $f(x)=f(x+p)$ by periodicity (though of course $x\neq x+p$.

Comment: Just from $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ there is no reason to believe that $x_1$ and $x_2$ are exactly one period apart. They might be equal. Instead, _start_ with $x_1$ and $x_2 = x_1+p \neq x_1$, and show that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, which disproves injectivity.

Comment: A proof by contradiction is convoluted compared with a constructive proof: to show that $f$ is not injective we need to find $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that $x_1 \neq x_2$ and $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$, As we are given that $f$ is periodic, say with period $p$, if we take any $x_1$ and put $x_2 = x_1 + p$ then $x_1$ and $x_2$ will meet our requirements.

Comment: Since $f$ is periodic, there is some $p \neq 0$ such that $f(x+p) = f(x)$. Since $x+p \neq x$ it follows that $f$ is not injective.

Comment: Every thing you say about x1 and x2 is pointless, muddled, confusing, and probably  but not necessarily wrong.  Just point out.  $p\ne 0$ so $x+p \ne x $, but $f (x+p) =f (x) $ so $f $ isn't injective.  That's all.

Comment: "Let x_1,x_2 be in domain f". Okay. They can be anything in the domain. "Since f is injective f (x1)=f(x2)" WHAT?!? If f is injective that is NOT the case unless x1 = x2. "So x1=x2" okay... but why did you pick two points. Why didn't you just pick one point and say "let x in Dom f"? Now you do stuff with three points x, x1, and x2. Why? You only need one so why did you bring in all this shit with x1 and x2? Just say f (*x*) = f (*x* +p). Therefore x = x +p therefore x-x =p. Why x1, x2 when *any* x would do?

Comment: Please don't deface a post. Once a question receives an answer, the question should remain largely unaltered.

Answer (score 3):

Your proof has one major flaw: the claim is false! It is easily fixed, however.

> Claim: Suppose $f$ is a function on some *non-empty* subset of the reals. If $f$ is periodic, then $f$ is non-injective.

At that point, you get the existence of a $p$ (as you mentioned) *and an* $x$! Then $x,x+p$ are distinct elements of the domain of $f,$ but $f(x)=f(x+p),$ so $f$ is not injective.